# Excel - Analyzing / Counting the comma separated values in cells

Tags: excel, analysis, multiple-value

Here's an Excel sheet, where we track Demand of Products across the countries *[Sheet/Table name: **Data**]*

| Country | Products |
| --- | --- |
| India | A |
| Australia | A,B |
| Brazil | B, C |

This Data will be used to understand the demand of the products across the countries, by simply counting products for each country. This is how the data will look like:

| Products | Demand |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 1 |

*[Sheet/Table name: **Product-Demand**]*

One of the ways, I was able to do this was :
Split the comma separated values in the Products Column/cell, and then **CountIFS**
However, this approach involved

1. Every time the **Data** table was updated, manually copy-pasting this to another sheet.
2. The products may increase, ex: new product "**Z**" may be launched
3. We use Power BI to create a heat-map of Products in demand across the country. The Power BI Service pulls the data every Monday. Manual effort kind of destroys the automation.

#### Please advise/guide on

What's the best way to count the products (or comma separated values) in a cell with least amount of manual work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Where the data is in columns A and B on both sheets, and there is a header row with the data starting in row 2, on the Product-Demand sheet, in cell B2, place this formula:

```
=COUNTIF(Data!$B$2:$B$4,"*" & A2 & "*")
```

then drag down

Answer (score 1):

You need to transform the data into a more useful structure. One way to do that is to use Power Query.
Start with your source data as a table called Table1.
Then, paste the following code in the Advanced Editor in Power Query:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Country", type text}, {"Products", type text}}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type"," ","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Products"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Replaced Value", "Products", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Products.1", "Products.2"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Products.1", type text}, {"Products.2", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type1", {"Country"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Columns",{"Attribute"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

This code will produce a table of usefully-structured data. The final table you want can be produced by a PivotTable using Power Query's output table as a source.